# In machine learning, what is definition of “downstream”?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've read the [PCA documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html
) of scikit-learn.

> [...] improve the predictive accuracy of the **downstream** estimators [...]

What is the definition of “downstream” in machine learning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know the term "downstream" from neural networks. In those machine learning algorithms, you have so called "neurons" which are usually in form of a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Downstream is everything after a certain neuron. You say neuron y is downstream of neuron x if and only if there is a directed path from x to y.

In a more general setting, I can only guess: y is downstream of x if and only if y uses data processed by x.

Answer (score 15):

The article you are citing refers to **whitening** and that is a *pre-processing* step (i.e upstream processing). "Downstream estimators" is a general term referring to the estimators employed after data preprocessing step.

Upstream processing (not exclusive list):

- Binarizer
- Bucketizer
- Products
- Normalizer
- Tokenizer
- Scaler
- Centralizer

Downstream estimators (not exclusive list):

- Logistic regression
- PCA
- Neural networks
- Boosting
- Gradient descents
- SVM
- GNN
- K-nn
- K-means
- Random Forest
- Hierarchical clustering